# Setting the minimum value of a pandas column using clip

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to set the `minimum` value of a column of `pandas` dataframe using `clip` method. Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'date' : pd.to_datetime(['2010-12-31', '2012-12-31', '2012-12-31']), 'val' : [1,2, 5]})
data.clip(lower=pd.Series({'val': 4}), axis=1)
```

Above code is giving error. Could you please help on how to eliminate the error?

Comment: You want `data['val'] = data['val'].clip(4)`?

Comment: Correct. Will you please answer then I can accept and close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Series.clip` or set the `date` column as index then `DataFrame.clip`.

```py
data['val'] = data['val'].clip(4)

# or

data = (data.set_index('date')
        .clip(4)
        .reset_index())
```

```
print(data)

        date  val
0 2010-12-31    4
1 2012-12-31    4
2 2012-12-31    5
```